# The integral of a sum?

Tags: summation, integral-equations

I was thinking if i could calculate the integral of a  sum ... and i started by a simple function ... f(x)=x; and to make it a little harder i tried to solve for a;
And here is the integral. ... integral (from 0 to a) of the sum (from x=1 to a) of x. All  is equal to 6.
Here are the steps i passed through to conclude that "a" is equal to 2. 
[image: my calculation of the integral]
So i want you to let me know if i did it correctly or no ?... and if it is correct ... then what is it's meaning ? (The area of a SUM ?? )
Thank you for your help.
PS : "a" is an integer.

Comment: To take the integral, you need to know what the sum with a non-integer upper bound means.

Comment: At least on my screen the text in the image is rotated and too light to be legible.  Please see the FAQ about MathJax

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that a is an integer

Comment: I edited my post thanks

Comment: A cubic equation has three roots, not one.

Comment: First we are working only in the integers

Comment: And secondly i just plugged the numbers from 0 to 5 and found that 2 is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your work is almost correct. That is, upto the integration and summation.

However, you must remember that a cubic equation has 3 roots, not just one. So the last step needs to be modified and the equation will be as follows:

$$a^3+a^2-12=0$$
$$(a-2)(a^2+3a+6)=0$$

So the roots of the quadratic equation are:
$$a=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-4\times1\times 6}}{2\cdot 1}$$
$$a=\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt{15}}{2}$$

So we get 2 complex conjugate roots. But since it is given that $a$ is an integer, so these two complex roots are not possible. $a = 2$ is the only answer.

Hope this helps you.